# Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object

Tags: php

```
$setEndedDate = ("UPDATE spaceships_list SET ended = :date WHERE id = :spaceship_id");
$setEndedDate->bindParam(":date", date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$setEndedDate->bindParam(":spaceship_id", $row["spaceship_id"]);
$setEnded->execute();
$endFlight = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM flights WHERE spaceship_id = :spaceship_id");
$endFlight->bindParam(":spaceship_id", $row["spaceship_id"]);
continue;
```

This returns error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object
```

with the line reffering to the line number 2 shown.

```
$setEndedDate->bindParam(":date", date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Not sure why I'm getting the error.

Comment: Perhaps because you are calling a member function (method) on a non-object? Obviously, $db->prepare did not return an object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941089/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-bindparam), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488035/call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-on-a-non-object), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921670/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-on-a-non-object), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401682/call-to-a-member-function-bindparam-on-a-non-object)

Comment: @PavelS. OP didn't even `prepare` on `$setEndedDate`

Comment: Oh, shoot. I didn't use $db->prepare! Thanks!

Comment: `$setEndedDate` is string it is not an object.

Answer (score 1):

your `$setEndedDate` is string it should be an object.

your problem is here:

```
$setEndedDate = ("UPDATE spaceships_list SET ended = :date WHERE id = :spaceship_id");
```

`$setEndedDate` it should be an object like `$endFlight`. you have correct object for `$endFlight` but you do not have object for  `$setEndedDate`.

try this:

```
$setEndedDate =  $db->prepare("UPDATE spaceships_list SET ended = :date WHERE id = :spaceship_id");
$setEndedDate->bindParam(":date", date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$setEndedDate->bindParam(":spaceship_id", $row["spaceship_id"]);
$setEnded->execute();
$endFlight = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM flights WHERE spaceship_id = :spaceship_id");
$endFlight->bindParam(":spaceship_id", $row["spaceship_id"]);
continue;
```